# Import requests module not working although it has already been installed properly

Tags: python, pip

My code is

```python
import requests
```

and and when I run this code I get:

`ImportError: No module named requests`

I already have requests installed on my mac:

[image]

Comment: check while running which python interpreter you are using.

Comment: Check which python do you use. To be sure that you install it to proper python env use: `python -m pip install <package>`

Answer (score 0):

try pip installing other packages to see if your import call can find it. if it couldn't work.  you have to reinstall python, in the set up, make sure you tick add python to path. if you do this and still get the same module error. use a another version of python

Comment: No point of reinstalling. It's clear that running pip installs package under different python env

Comment: many things can lead to that error though. its either python is not added to path or its a version issue. maybe you should pip install a lower version of requests